# Should I store map<key, value> to database or just clone object to file?

Tags: android, database

I use a Hashmap to cache database rw. if all data not huge, why not just clone the Hashmap to binary file? I tried and it works. I'm beginner, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are planning to do with the map. If the usable of the data is to use it like a map all the time and the data is not huge as you said, just storing to file would be the best. Less time to implement, less code to maintain, and you got the functionality you need out-of-the-box.

On the other hand, if you need anything more complicated than that, for example search for a particular pair, or do some sort of complex filtering of the data, it would be better to use a database for that.

tl;dr:
**File**:

- pros : faster and easy to implement
- cons : the functionality you get is standard

**Database**

- pros : easier to 'search for data', and use the data in many different ways
- cons : takes more effort to implement and maintain.